# OpenCV: Why OCL module is absent in master branch?

Tags: opencv, opencl

System Info: WIndows 7 , 64 bit on INtel celeron dual core 
I am building OpenCV library from master branch. After following all the instructions in opencv doc, I got my build directory. But I found that my OCL directory is missing. i,e here:
C:\Users\Hesh\Documents\opencv_built\modules

Why it is happening?

This was the output from cmake generate:

```
The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 16.0.30319.1
The C compiler identification is MSVC 16.0.30319.1
Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 10 2010 Win64
ICV: Unpacking ippicv_windows_20140429.zip to C:/Users/Hesh/Documents/opencv_source/opencv/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack...
ICV: Package successfully downloaded
found IPP (ICV version): 8.1.1 [8.1.1]
at: C:/Users/Hesh/Documents/opencv_source/opencv/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_win
Could NOT find PythonInterp (missing:  PYTHON_EXECUTABLE) (Required is at least version "2.7")
Could NOT find PythonInterp (missing:  PYTHON_EXECUTABLE) (Required is at least version "2.6")
Could NOT find JNI (missing:  JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH) 
Could NOT find Matlab (missing:  MATLAB_MEX_SCRIPT MATLAB_INCLUDE_DIRS MATLAB_ROOT_DIR MATLAB_LIBRARIES MATLAB_LIBRARY_DIRS MATLAB_MEXEXT MATLAB_ARCH MATLAB_BIN) 
VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:795 (get_target_property):
  Policy CMP0026 is not set: Disallow use of the LOCATION target property.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0026" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The LOCATION property should not be read from target "opencv_test_core".
  Use the target name directly with add_custom_command, or use the generator
  expression $<TARGET_FILE>, as appropriate.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  modules/core/CMakeLists.txt:28 (ocv_add_accuracy_tests)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:795 (get_target_property):
  Policy CMP0026 is not set: Disallow use of the LOCATION target property.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0026" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The LOCATION property should not be read from target "opencv_test_flann".
  Use the target name directly with add_custom_command, or use the generator
  expression $<TARGET_FILE>, as appropriate.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:655 (ocv_add_accuracy_tests)
  modules/flann/CMakeLists.txt:2 (ocv_define_module)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:795 (get_target_property):
  Policy CMP0026 is not set: Disallow use of the LOCATION target property.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0026" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The LOCATION property should not be read from target "opencv_test_imgproc".
  Use the target name directly with add_custom_command, or use the generator
  expression $<TARGET_FILE>, as appropriate.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:655 (ocv_add_accuracy_tests)
  modules/imgproc/CMakeLists.txt:2 (ocv_define_module)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:795 (get_target_property):
  Policy CMP0026 is not set: Disallow use of the LOCATION target property.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0026" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The LOCATION property should not be read from target
  "opencv_test_imgcodecs".  Use the target name directly with
  add_custom_command, or use the generator expression $<TARGET_FILE>, as
  appropriate.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  modules/imgcodecs/CMakeLists.txt:130 (ocv_add_accuracy_tests)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:795 (get_target_property):
  Policy CMP0026 is not set: Disallow use of the LOCATION target property.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0026" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The LOCATION property should not be read from target "opencv_test_highgui".
  Use the target name directly with add_custom_command, or use the generator
  expression $<TARGET_FILE>, as appropriate.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  modules/highgui/CMakeLists.txt:125 (ocv_add_accuracy_tests)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:795 (get_target_property):
  Policy CMP0026 is not set: Disallow use of the LOCATION target property.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0026" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The LOCATION property should not be read from target
  "opencv_test_features2d".  Use the target name directly with
  add_custom_command, or use the generator expression $<TARGET_FILE>, as
  appropriate.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:655 (ocv_add_accuracy_tests)
  modules/features2d/CMakeLists.txt:2 (ocv_define_module)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:795 (get_target_property):
  Policy CMP0026 is not set: Disallow use of the LOCATION target property.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0026" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The LOCATION property should not be read from target "opencv_test_calib3d".
  Use the target name directly with add_custom_command, or use the generator
  expression $<TARGET_FILE>, as appropriate.
```

cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:655 (ocv_add_accuracy_tests)
      modules/video/CMakeLists.txt:2 (ocv_define_module)
    This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

```
CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:795 (get_target_property):
  Policy CMP0026 is not set: Disallow use of the LOCATION target property.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0026" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The LOCATION property should not be read from target "opencv_test_shape".
  Use the target name directly with add_custom_command, or use the generator
  expression $<TARGET_FILE>, as appropriate.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:655 (ocv_add_accuracy_tests)
  modules/shape/CMakeLists.txt:2 (ocv_define_module)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:795 (get_target_property):
  Policy CMP0026 is not set: Disallow use of the LOCATION target property.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0026" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The LOCATION property should not be read from target
  "opencv_test_stitching".  Use the target name directly with
  add_custom_command, or use the generator expression $<TARGET_FILE>, as
  appropriate.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:655 (ocv_add_accuracy_tests)
  modules/stitching/CMakeLists.txt:2 (ocv_define_module)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:795 (get_target_property):
  Policy CMP0026 is not set: Disallow use of the LOCATION target property.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0026" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The LOCATION property should not be read from target "opencv_test_videoio".
  Use the target name directly with add_custom_command, or use the generator
  expression $<TARGET_FILE>, as appropriate.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  modules/videoio/CMakeLists.txt:233 (ocv_add_accuracy_tests)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:795 (get_target_property):
  Policy CMP0026 is not set: Disallow use of the LOCATION target property.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0026" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The LOCATION property should not be read from target
  "opencv_test_superres".  Use the target name directly with
  add_custom_command, or use the generator expression $<TARGET_FILE>, as
  appropriate.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:655 (ocv_add_accuracy_tests)
  modules/superres/CMakeLists.txt:7 (ocv_define_module)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/OpenCVGenPkgconfig.cmake:40 (get_target_property):
  Policy CMP0026 is not set: Disallow use of the LOCATION target property.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0026" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The LOCATION property should not be read from target "opencv_calib3d".  Use
  the target name directly with add_custom_command, or use the generator
  expression $<TARGET_FILE>, as appropriate.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:560 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/OpenCVGenPkgconfig.cmake:40 (get_target_property):
  Policy CMP0026 is not set: Disallow use of the LOCATION target property.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0026" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The LOCATION property should not be read from target "opencv_core".  Use
  the target name directly with add_custom_command, or use the generator
  expression $<TARGET_FILE>, as appropriate.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:560 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/OpenCVGenPkgconfig.cmake:40 (get_target_property):
  Policy CMP0026 is not set: Disallow use of the LOCATION target property.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0026" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The LOCATION property should not be read from target "opencv_features2d".
  Use the target name directly with add_custom_command, or use the generator
  expression $<TARGET_FILE>, as appropriate.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:560 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/OpenCVGenPkgconfig.cmake:40 (get_target_property):
  Policy CMP0026 is not set: Disallow use of the LOCATION target property.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0026" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The LOCATION property should not be read from target "opencv_flann".  Use
  the target name directly with add_custom_command, or use the generator
  expression $<TARGET_FILE>, as appropriate.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:560 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/OpenCVGenPkgconfig.cmake:40 (get_target_property):
  Policy CMP0026 is not set: Disallow use of the LOCATION target property.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0026" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The LOCATION property should not be read from target "opencv_highgui".  Use
  the target name directly with add_custom_command, or use the generator
  expression $<TARGET_FILE>, as appropriate.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:560 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/OpenCVGenPkgconfig.cmake:40 (get_target_property):
  Policy CMP0026 is not set: Disallow use of the LOCATION target property.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0026" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The LOCATION property should not be read from target "opencv_imgcodecs".
  Use the target name directly with add_custom_command, or use the generator
  expression $<TARGET_FILE>, as appropriate.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:560 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/OpenCVGenPkgconfig.cmake:40 (get_target_property):
  Policy CMP0026 is not set: Disallow use of the LOCATION target property.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0026" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The LOCATION property should not be read from target "opencv_imgproc".  Use
  the target name directly with add_custom_command, or use the generator
  expression $<TARGET_FILE>, as appropriate.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:560 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/OpenCVGenPkgconfig.cmake:40 (get_target_property):
  Policy CMP0026 is not set: Disallow use of the LOCATION target property.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0026" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The LOCATION property should not be read from target "opencv_ml".  Use the
  target name directly with add_custom_command, or use the generator
  expression $<TARGET_FILE>, as appropriate.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:560 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/OpenCVGenPkgconfig.cmake:40 (get_target_property):
  Policy CMP0026 is not set: Disallow use of the LOCATION target property.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0026" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The LOCATION property should not be read from target "opencv_nonfree".  Use
  the target name directly with add_custom_command, or use the generator
  expression $<TARGET_FILE>, as appropriate.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:560 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/OpenCVGenPkgconfig.cmake:40 (get_target_property):
  Policy CMP0026 is not set: Disallow use of the LOCATION target property.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0026" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The LOCATION property should not be read from target "opencv_objdetect".
  Use the target name directly with add_custom_command, or use the generator
  expression $<TARGET_FILE>, as appropriate.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:560 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/OpenCVGenPkgconfig.cmake:40 (get_target_property):
  Policy CMP0026 is not set: Disallow use of the LOCATION target property.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0026" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The LOCATION property should not be read from target "opencv_optim".  Use
  the target name directly with add_custom_command, or use the generator
  expression $<TARGET_FILE>, as appropriate.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:560 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/OpenCVGenPkgconfig.cmake:40 (get_target_property):
  Policy CMP0026 is not set: Disallow use of the LOCATION target property.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0026" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The LOCATION property should not be read from target "opencv_photo".  Use
  the target name directly with add_custom_command, or use the generator
  expression $<TARGET_FILE>, as appropriate.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:560 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/OpenCVGenPkgconfig.cmake:40 (get_target_property):
  Policy CMP0026 is not set: Disallow use of the LOCATION target property.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0026" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The LOCATION property should not be read from target "opencv_shape".  Use
  the target name directly with add_custom_command, or use the generator
  expression $<TARGET_FILE>, as appropriate.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:560 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/OpenCVGenPkgconfig.cmake:40 (get_target_property):
  Policy CMP0026 is not set: Disallow use of the LOCATION target property.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0026" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The LOCATION property should not be read from target "opencv_stitching".
  Use the target name directly with add_custom_command, or use the generator
  expression $<TARGET_FILE>, as appropriate.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:560 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/OpenCVGenPkgconfig.cmake:40 (get_target_property):
  Policy CMP0026 is not set: Disallow use of the LOCATION target property.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0026" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The LOCATION property should not be read from target "opencv_superres".
  Use the target name directly with add_custom_command, or use the generator
  expression $<TARGET_FILE>, as appropriate.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:560 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/OpenCVGenPkgconfig.cmake:40 (get_target_property):
  Policy CMP0026 is not set: Disallow use of the LOCATION target property.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0026" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The LOCATION property should not be read from target "opencv_ts".  Use the
  target name directly with add_custom_command, or use the generator
  expression $<TARGET_FILE>, as appropriate.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:560 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/OpenCVGenPkgconfig.cmake:40 (get_target_property):
  Policy CMP0026 is not set: Disallow use of the LOCATION target property.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0026" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The LOCATION property should not be read from target "opencv_video".  Use
  the target name directly with add_custom_command, or use the generator
  expression $<TARGET_FILE>, as appropriate.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:560 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/OpenCVGenPkgconfig.cmake:40 (get_target_property):
  Policy CMP0026 is not set: Disallow use of the LOCATION target property.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0026" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The LOCATION property should not be read from target "opencv_videoio".  Use
  the target name directly with add_custom_command, or use the generator
  expression $<TARGET_FILE>, as appropriate.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:560 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/OpenCVGenPkgconfig.cmake:40 (get_target_property):
  Policy CMP0026 is not set: Disallow use of the LOCATION target property.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0026" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The LOCATION property should not be read from target "opencv_videostab".
  Use the target name directly with add_custom_command, or use the generator
  expression $<TARGET_FILE>, as appropriate.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:560 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.


General configuration for OpenCV 3.0.0-dev =====================================
  Version control:               2.4.9-4336-g9e3124a

  Platform:
    Host:                        Windows 6.1 AMD64
    CMake:                       3.0.0
    CMake generator:             Visual Studio 10 2010 Win64
    CMake build tool:            C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/MSBuild.exe
    MSVC:                        1600

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++ Compiler:                c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe  (ver 16.0.30319.1)
    C++ flags (Release):         /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR /EHa  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /wd4251 /MD /O2 /Ob2 /D NDEBUG  /Zi
    C++ flags (Debug):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR /EHa  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /wd4251 /D_DEBUG /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
    C Compiler:                  c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
    C flags (Release):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /MD /O2 /Ob2 /D NDEBUG  /Zi
    C flags (Debug):             /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /D_DEBUG /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
    Linker flags (Release):      /machine:x64   /INCREMENTAL:NO  /debug
    Linker flags (Debug):        /machine:x64   /debug /INCREMENTAL 
    Precompiled headers:         YES

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 core flann imgproc imgcodecs highgui features2d calib3d ml nonfree objdetect optim photo video shape stitching videoio superres ts videostab
    Disabled:                    world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 androidcamera cuda cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev java matlab python viz

  Windows RT support:            NO

    Use GCD                      NO
    Use Concurrency              YES
    Use C=:                      NO
    Use Cuda:                    NO
    Use OpenCL:                  YES

  OpenCL:
    Version:                     dynamic
    Include path:                C:/Users/Hesh/Documents/opencv_source/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Use AMDFFT:                  NO
    Use AMDBLAS:                 NO

  Python:
    Interpreter:                 NO

  Java:
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Matlab:
    mex:                         NO

  Tests and samples:
    Tests:                       YES
    Performance tests:           YES
    C/C++ Examples:              NO

  Install path:                  C:/Users/Hesh/Documents/opencv_built/install

  cvconfig.h is in:              C:/Users/Hesh/Documents/opencv_built
-----------------------------------------------------------------

Configuring done
```

You can see, it says Use OpenCL = YES, then why is the module OCL is not coming ?

**Edit**

I found that actually in master branch under modules, OCL is missing:

See here:

https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/modules

But it is there in 2.4.9.x

https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/2.4.9.x-prep/modules

Why it like that ?

I wanted to build libraries for 3.0.0, I think that is possible only from master branch, but now since it is missing OCL modules, what do I do ?    I need OCL in latest 3.0.0

Comment: This happens due the missing graphics driver compatible with OpenCL. When no OpenCL headers are available, then OpenCL module is not built

Comment: I have run simple OpenCL programs, separartly, and have also run clinfo.exe, which reports the presence of gpu. I noticed that my source folder from which I am generating libraries is also not having the folder OCL. Is the issue    ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The master branch of OpenCV has switched over to a "Transparent API" design.  This API puts CPU and OpenCL implementations together under a unified API.  So there's no longer a need for a separate "ocl" module.  Here's a presentation that describes the change: [presentation](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1qoa29N_B-s297-fp0-b3rBirvpzJQp8dCtllLQ4DVCY/present#slide=id.p24).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Does that mean I will not have to locate any opencl specific dll?

Comment: OpenCV won't have any OpenCL-specific DLLs.  There are still OpenCL DLLs that come with your graphics driver, or whatever OpenCL implementation you are using, but that's completely separate from OpenCV.